# Checking the state of a ReentrantReadWriteLock (locked for read/write, threads waiting)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I am implementing a `DocumentProvider` that must support concurrent access to the `Document`s it provides. Here's roughly how it works:

- Documents are loaded on demand.
- While a document is being used it is kept in `activeDocuments` (a `Map<String, Document>` indexed by document id).
- After a document stops being used, it is moved from `activeDocuments` to `idleDocuments` (also a `Map<String, Document>` indexed by document id). `idleDocuments` is a LRU cache, which means at some point a `Document` in this cache may be discarded.
- Each document may be accessed for reading or writing, with the usual readers/writers policy. This is implemented using a [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) per active `Document`.
- Attempts to lock documents are non-locking: a thread will invoke `tryLock` instead of `lock`. If it fails to lock the document, a `CannotLockException` is thrown and the thread will have to deal with it -- how exactly is beyond the scope of this question. (Example: showing a message "The document is currently locked. Would you like to open a read-only copy?")

Here's the code (a bit simplified):

```
public enum LockMode {
   READ,
   WRITE;
}
```

```
public class DocumentManager {

    /**
     * Documents currently in use (indexed by documentId).<br>
     * Always accessed in a synchronized(activeDocuments) block.
     */
    private Map<String, Document> activeDocuments;

    /**
     * Documents that have been loaded but are not in use (indexed by
     * documentId). This is a LRU cache and documents may be discarded if the
     * cache is full.<br>
     * Always accessed in a synchronized(activeDocuments) block.
     */
    private Map<String, Document> idleDocuments;

    /**
     * Read/write locks in for the {@link #activeDocuments} (indexed by
     * documentId).<br>
     * Always accessed in a synchronized(readWriteLocks) block.
     */
    private Map<String, ReentrantReadWriteLock> readWriteLocks;

    public Document openDocument(String documentId, LockMode lockMode) throws CannotLockException {
        Document document = null;
        synchronized (activeDocuments) {
            document = activeDocuments.get(documentId);
            if (document == null) {
                document = loadDocument(documentId);
                activeDocuments.put(documentId, document);
            }
        }
        if (document != null) {
            tryLock(documentId, lockMode);
        }
        return document;
    }

    protected Document loadDocument(String documentId) {
        synchronized (activeDocuments) {
            Document document = idleDocuments.remove(documentId);
            if (document == null) {
                document = // load the document from disk
            }
            return document;
        }
    }

    public void tryLock(String documentId, LockMode lockMode) throws CannotLockException {
       synchronized (readWriteLocks) {
          ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = readWriteLocks.get(documentId);
          if (readWriteLock == null) {
             readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
             readWriteLocks.put(documentId, readWriteLock);
          }
          Lock lock = getLock(readWriteLock, lockMode);
          if (!lock.tryLock()) {
              throw new CannotLockException("Cannot lock document " + documentId + " for " + lockMode);
          }
       }
    }

    public void unlock(String documentId) throws CannotUnlockException {
        ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = null;
        synchronized (readWriteLocks) {
            readWriteLock = readWriteLocks.get(documentId);

            if (readWriteLock == null) {
                throw new CannotUnlockException("Cannot unlock document " + documentId
                        + ": it is not currently locked");
            }

            Lock lock = null;
            // (1) From isWriteLocked's javadoc:
            // Queries if the write lock is held by any thread. This method is
            // designed for use in monitoring system state, not for
            // synchronization control.
            if (readWriteLock.isWriteLocked()) {
                lock = readWriteLock.writeLock();
            } else {
                lock = readWriteLock.readLock();
            }
            try {
                lock.unlock();
            } catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
                throw new CannotUnlockException("Cannot unlock document " + documentId
                        + ": this thread does not own any lock on it", e);
            }

            // (2) From hasQueuedThreads's javadoc:
            // Queries whether any threads are waiting to acquire the read or
            // write lock. Note that because cancellations may occur at any
            // time, a true return does not guarantee that any other thread will
            // ever acquire a lock. This method is designed primarily for use in
            // monitoring of the system state.
            if (!readWriteLock.hasQueuedThreads() &&
                // (3) From getReadLockCount's javadoc:
                // Queries the number of read locks held for this lock. This
                // method is designed for use in monitoring system state, not
                // for synchronization control.
                readWriteLock.getReadLockCount() == 0) {
                synchronized (activeDocuments) {
                    Document document = activeDocuments.remove(documentId);
                    idleDocuments.put(documentId, document);
                    // Remove the lock from the map to free some space.
                    readWriteLocks.remove(documentId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected Lock getLock(ReentrantReadWriteLock lock, LockMode lockMode) {
       switch (lockMode) {
       case READ:
          return lock.readLock();
       case WRITE:
          return lock.readLock();
       default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown " + LockMode.class.getName() + ": " + lockMode);
       }
    }

}
```

As you may have seen in my comments in the code, there are several points in method `unlock` (marked as (1), (2), (3)) where I invoke methods whose Javadoc indicates that they are meant to be used for monitoring, not for synchronization. Obviously this is not ok, so I'm looking for an alternative. The methods in question check whether a given `ReentrantReadWriteLock` is currently locked for reading ((3), `getReadLockCount`) or writing ((1), `isWriteLocked`) and whether there are threads queuing on the lock ((2), `hasQueuedThreads` -- admittedly not relevant in my current `tryLock` scenario, but I would still like to check). Basically, I want to know whether the document in question has just gone from *active* to *idle* (no one wants to use it any more) and I can therefore move it from `activeDocuments` to `idleDocuments`.

I could keep the state (locked for reading/writing, threads waiting) in `DocumentProvider`, but I'd rather avoid this is if the lock has (or has access to) the necessary information. I was looking at the methods mentioned above (`isWriteLocked`, 
`getReadLockCount`, `hasQueuedThreads`) and it seems to me that in my particular scenario these methods should reflect the actual state of the lock, since any action that may modify the state of the lock is always carried out inside a `synchronized (readWriteLocks) {}` block, so the state of the lock should not change while I invoke one of those potentially unsafe methods.

Do you agree?
If not, should I keep this information externally to the lock, in `DocumentProvider`?

Btw, if anyone sees any synchronization problem with the code (e.g., a possible deadlock), I would really appreciate a heads-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `ReentrantReadWriteLock` locks manually, instead of using system ones. (Note, that java lock expects unlocking be performed from the *same thread*, which locked it before.) Because you don't use blocking lock, implementation is straightforward:

```
class MyReentrantReadWriteLock {
    private int state; // 0 - free, -1 - write locked, n>0 - read locked n times
    public bool tryLock(LockMode lockMode) {
        switch(lockMode) {
        case READ:
            if(state == -1) return false; // Already write-locked.
            state++;
            return true;
        case WRITE:
            if(state) return false; // Already locked.
            state = -1;
            return true;
        }
    public void unlock() {
         switch(state) {
         case 0:
             // error: not locked
         case -1:
             state = 0; // write unlock
             break;
         default:
             state--; // read unlock
         }
    }
    public bool isLocked() {
        return state != 0;
    }
};
```

Because you use locks only under `synchronized (readWriteLocks)`, your locks implementation needn't worry about sync.

**UPDATE**: If you want to use more complex things with document's locks, such as condition variables, it is better to differentiate *locking*, which grants read or write access, and *usage counting*, which prevents document from being unloaded while used.

With usage counter, the only monitoring method of the `ReentrantReadWriteLock` you need is `.isWriteLocked` for determine lock type during unlock. Though it is better to deduct that property from somewhere else.

**Better design** would be:

1. Store `lockMode` inside `Document` object. E.g., as `bool m_isWritable;`
2. Replace `ReentrantReadWriteLock` in `readWriteLocks` field definition with any reference count class(and, probably, rename field itself).

This allows for `DocumentManager` for being true factory object, which prohibits (e.g., throw exception) to open document, if it is already opened as writable(and vice versa).

From the other side, thread, which use document, can pass it by *reference* to any auxiliary function, and this function can check, whether document is writable:

```
// User of the document
{
    doc = documentManager.openDocument("doc1", WRITE);
    //...
    doSomethingWithDocument(doc);
    //...
    documentManager.closeDocument(doc);
}

// Implementation of auxiliary function
void doSomethingWithDocument(Document doc) {
     if(!doc.isWritable()) throw new Exception("Read-only document!");
     // Process document
}
```

With that implementation you don't need reentrant locking (all calls to `openDocument()` are treated as request for *new* document reference). As for lock downgrading, it may be implemented as simple method in `DocumentManager`:

```
void makeReadOnly(Document doc)
{
     synchronized(readWriteLocks)
     {
         doc->m_isWritable = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Tsyvarev, thank you for your answer, but this is not the same as a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. For example, it doesn't implement the properties "Reentrancy", "Lock downgrading" and "Condition support", all of which I need in my use case (even though I did not explicitly state it in the question). You can read about these properties here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html.

Comment: Furthermore, it is strongly recommended to use the `java.util.concurrent` classes rather than rolling your own (whenever possible) since concurrency is notoriously difficult to get right and these classes are already tested and proved to work correctly.

Comment: I can imaging usage of document's locking "Reentrancy" and "Lock downgrading" (BTW, this property cat be easily implemented in my class). But using conditions seems weird: It is possible to have *locked* but *unloaded* document when `Condition.await` returns. Note, that `lock.hasQueuedThreads()` doesn't take into account threads, waiting on condition. You better have explicit *usage counting* (see my updated answer).

Comment: True, my mistake: I am using conditions on a different set of locks, so this is not relevant for this question; sorry about that. However, I still don't feel comfortable with the idea of using a custom-written lock (even a non-locking one); it goes against all recommendations I have seen. Do you agree with my statement above that since I always access the locks in `synchronized (readWriteLocks) {}` blocks it is safe for me to use the `isWriteLocked`, `getReadLockCount`, `hasQueuedThreads` methods? Would you advice against this for some reason?

Comment: Yes, synchronized usage of lock's methods is fine(safe). BTW, `hasQueuedThreads()` is always `false`, because you doesn't use *blocking* methods of lock.  The only cons. against using these methods - their original `monitoring` purpose. Needs of such methods in normal code usually signals about wrong architecture decision.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I know about `hasQueuedThreads`: in my question I wrote "admittedly not relevant in my current tryLock scenario, but I would still like to check". About "wrong architecture decision": the "right" one, in your opinion, would be keeping this thread count information in my `DocumentProvider`? I'm undecided because duplicating information isn't nice either.

Comment: I updated my answer with info how design can be improved.

Comment: Tsyvarev, thanks for your answers. Unfortunately I cannot implement the solution you suggest because it contradicts some of my requirements (which you don't know about), but since this may work for other people and you've put effort into making new suggestions every time I've asked, I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks!